# Magento 2 Add css class to <a> tag in customer account navigation

Tags: magento2, css, page-layouts

I try to assign a CSS class to **navigation** ( tag) under **customer account** page.

I found this file *customer_account.xml*, and I added                                 `<argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sidebar-navigation__item-link</argument>`
 to the block, as following

```
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface"
                           name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sidebar-navigation__item-link</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/addresss</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">190</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```

But this doesn't give any effect on the frontpage. I have cleared the cache.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-2">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders 2</argument>
        <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">230</argument>
        <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">my_custom_link</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks. how come I didn't know this.

Comment: I want to add class to li and not a. Because once the 'current' class is added to li, the child is changed to 'strong' instead of anchor. Please help.

Comment: when I try to add class it adds class but removes add other tabs on account navigation @Sohel Rana

Comment: @SejalShah have you found any solution for your requirement?